# Quirk with printing union values

Tags: c, printf, unions

The below code results in:

0.000000

10

What is being returned from 'data' in this case? I know `n.data.idata` and `n.data.fdata` would be the correct usage, I'm just curious as to why the integer value works in this case and the float value does not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    union container
    {
        int idata;
        float fdata;
    } data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

int main()
{
    Node i = {.data.idata = 10};
    Node n = {.data.fdata = 10.0};
    printf("%f\n", n.data);
    printf("%d\n", i.data);

    printf("\nExiting program...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should work with neither of these, as `data` is neither `int` nor `float`..

Comment: Maybe `n.data` returns on default the first element, but not sure about that.

Comment: I bet if you swap the order of the two vars in your struct the behavior will switch to printing the float but not the int. See if that helps you think through it.

Comment: In C lingo, what happens is **undefined behavior** since you pass an object of type `union container` to printf expecting a float or int.

Comment: Would be more insightful `printf("%e\n", n.data);` (e vs f), But it UB either way.

Comment: @Jens I think we're just curious about what undefined behavior is actually happening.

Comment: @vestlen I tried that, same results. However, changing fdata from a float to a double has given me the correct value for both data types.

Comment: @Philipp Braun  `n.data` does not pass the first element of `n.data`, it passes the entire `n.data`. (which happens to be the same size as it first element as it only has one.)

Comment: @IanStone Exactly, see my answer. While the code is still undefined, that result is (somewhat) expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ignore the obvious undefined behavior for a moment, which happens because an incorrect type is passed to the printf function for the specifier `f`. That type being an anonymous union.

Specifier `f` assumes a default argument promotion from float to double,  which doesn't happen in this case, because a union `data` is passed to the function. So the function receives the union `data` which consists of 4 bytes and represents a float, but tries to print 8 bytes, because it expects a double. The result is a nonsense value, in your case 0.0.

(This answer assumes IEEE 754, and sizeof(int)<=4)

Comment: Note: `printf("%d\n", i.data);` is also UB.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for my original answer to the wrong question. I think this answer 
might help clarify for people coming to this question who are new to C what 2501 is talking about (emphasis mine)

> Specifier f assumes a default argument promotion from float to double,
>   which **doesn't happen in this case**, because a union data is passed to
>   the function. So the function receives the union data which consists
>   of 4 bytes and represents a float, but tries to print 8 bytes, because
>   it expects a double. The result is a nonsense value, in your case 0.0.

Type promotion converts one binary representation to another safely or at least
in a standardized way. The following was all done on an x86 machine.

The value in binary of `10` in unsigned 64 bit format

> |0**1**0**1**0000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000

Binary value of 10 as a 32 bit float...

> |00000000|00000000|00000**1**00|**1**00000**1**0

The value of 10 as a double in 64 bit format...

> |00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000|00**1**00**1**00|000000**1**0

All three representations of the number 10 differ significantly. Type promotion 
not happening means that the number in the `printf` statement was seen as a
double and it was printed as such. In this case the only reason it showed up as
a zero was precision.

The `Node` data structure in the following code is 8 bytes. There is no padding
in the struct or it could not be 8 bytes long. If we set the `float` to 10 and `next` 
to 0 we have this representation in memory...

> |00000000|00000000|00000**1**00|**1**00000**1**0|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000000

The above if converted to a double and printed with `printf("%f'\n");` makes it
look like a `0.0`. If you print it using 'printf("%g\n")' you wqould see that some 
bits must be set in the 8 bytes, in my case I got

```
5.39824e-315
```

To see what the floats class can use `fpclassify`. See code below...

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  union container {
    float fdata;
    int idata;
  } data;
  uint32_t next;
} Node;

int main(void) {
  size_t nsize1 = sizeof(Node);
  assert(nsize1 == 8); 
  assert(sizeof(int)    == 4); 
  assert(sizeof(float)  == 4); 
  assert(sizeof(double) == 8); 
  Node  n   = {.data.fdata = 10.0};
  n.next = 0;
  double   d              = *(double*)&n;
  int    class_of_d       = fpclassify(d);
  assert(d > 0); 
  switch(class_of_d) {
    case FP_NAN        : printf("FP_NAN\n");break;
    case FP_INFINITE   : printf("FP_INFINITE\n");break;
    case FP_ZERO       : printf("FP_ZERO\n");break;
    case FP_NORMAL     : printf("FP_NORMAL\n");break;
    case FP_SUBNORMAL  : printf("FP_SUBNORMAL\n");break;
    case FP_SUPERNORMAL: printf("FP_SUPERNORMAL\n");break;
  }
  printf("%g\n", d); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: He already knew this, as per his question. He was looking for an explanation for the current output.

Comment: I added it to the answer